# Backend in German Typo3 Version 9.5.5 Language Extension missing in Admin Tool

Tags: localhost, admin, typo3-extensions, typo3-9.x

I am running Typo3 Version 9.5.5 on my localhost. I want my backend to be in German. Unfortunately I cannot access the Extension Manager to install languages and the language panel, which is supposed to be in the Admin Tools, is missing.

I tried to look for the languages in the User Settings and Maintenance. In Maintenance I tried to go for "mangage language packs" but there this error message occured:

```
Something went wrong. Please use Check for broken extensions to see if a loaded 
extension breaks this part of the install tool and unload it.

The box below may additionally reveal further details on what went wrong depending 
on your debug settings. It may help to temporarily switch to debug mode using 
`Settings > Configuration Presets > Debug settings`.

If this error happens at an early state and no full exception back trace is shown, 
it may also help to manually increase debugging output in 
`typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php:
   ['BE']['debug'] => true, 
   ['SYS']['devIPmask'] => '*', 
   ['SYS']['displayErrors'] => 1,
   ['SYS']['systemLogLevel'] => 0, 
   ['SYS']['exceptionalErrors'] => 12290`
```

I'd be glad If anyone has an idea how to fix this.

Comment: Please follow the given advice to active the debug settings and report the error messages. I would also remove all non system extensions and then activate the extensions again one by one to check which one causes the problem.

Comment: This Typo3 project was newly installed, I haven't touched the code yet.
Besides If I selct a page under the mount point, go to the "List" menue and want to enter a new record > New Backend Layout, this Icon and the option "new Backend Layout" is also missing. It seems like I cannot fully access the extensions unser Apache Localhost. Nevertheless I can manually setup a Backend Layout using the TSConfig Panel. So where is my Backend Layout Wizard where I can set up the columns easily? Do I have to activate it somewhere? This is all very strange...

Answer (score 0):

you find it in 9.5, when you open the Maintenance section and scroll down. There you have "Manage Language Packs". it moved from the admin tool into here.